# Using zip function for combining long list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7, zip

suppose I have a list as

```
mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
```

If I want to add element-by-element then I can use logic as:

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(mylist[0],mylist[1],mylist[2],mylist[3],mylist[4],mylist[6]]
```

and it will give sum of columnwise elements. 
But the problem is , writing each index of mylist inside zip function is somewhat awkward and vague if mylist happens to be list of say 1000 lists and I need to do the element by element operation.

I tried putting loop inside the zip function but it doesn't work. So any idea for that??

It should work like

```
zip(for k in mylist) # or something else
```

Thanks

Comment: In your example, 'zip' will give you a list of 6-uples...

Comment: Your example has a syntax error and a logic error in it, just try to run it. But I think what you are looking for is ``zip(*mylist)``.

Comment: Look at 'reduce': http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, that looks more obvious here, is to use the built-in `map` with `sum` along side `zip` on an unpacked list

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*mylist))
[51, 57, 63]
```

And if you are a fan of generators, the following might add some benefits

```
>>> from itertools import izip, imap
>>> list(imap(sum, izip(*mylist)))
[51, 57, 63]
```

Answer (score 3):

To sum all the first elements, all the second elements and so on:

```
In [2]: [sum(k) for k in zip(*mylist)]
Out[2]: [51, 57, 63]
```

Note that each number in the output is a sum of `len(mylist)` numbers:

```
In [3]: zip(*mylist)
Out[3]: [(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16), (2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17), (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)]
```

[The `*` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) unpacks `mylist` so that its items become separate arguments to `zip`.